# SQL Developer Quits on Open

Tags: installation, ide, oracle-sqldeveloper

My SqlDeveloper app has been working normally since installation. Now, when I open it, everything seems normal ... until it quits itself. I have enough time to see what's happening, then the window just closes itself.

Here's what I've tried:
-deleting the two folders in AppData\Roaming like other posts say to do
-uninstall + fresh reinstall

Neither worked. I was shocked when the reinstalled version exhibited the exact same behavior. If it's not obvious, such an insidious problem is happening on a Win10 machine.

UPDATE - thanks jeff - here's my CL output

[image]

I also have a log file, but it exceeds the SO limit

Comment: So javaFX is crashing the windows jvm.dll - two things to try - if you can, uncheck the 'Show on startup' checkbox in the welcome page, and then close that page. If you're not able to do that before the crash, I would go get an Oracle Java 8 JDK and tell SQL Developer to use that

Comment: havent been able to get to the startup checkbox. jdk8 was already installed, i reinstalled to no avail. whats the best way to specify JDK for sqldev? edit bin/sqldeveloper.conf?

Comment: no, edit product.conf - i show how here https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/03/on-installs-and-updates-of-sql-developer/

Comment: it worked! thank you!

Comment: excellent, thanks for letting us know Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly likely the windows video driver is crashing the java jvm.

Start SQL Developer from the /bin folder.

WHen it 'crashes', inspect the CMD window for any error messages or the java stack dump.

[image]

This is discussed on our product forums [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4144119).

Comment: @mike-palmice, any news?

Comment: jeff, thank you for your reply, and all your contributions to the community. its a real honor

Comment: No, the honor is MINE. And you're very welcome of course.